# Try to deal with simple inequilities in sympy integration

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I'm trying to do some interesting integration problems for my Calculus I students  under Anaconda python 3.8.5 and sympy version 1.9,

So question 1 is:

integrate(sin(m * x)* cos(n * x), x)

[image]

whereas x is the integration variable and m and n are 2 unequal and uncomplement (m != -n) real constants.

Question 2 is: integrate((a ** 2 - x ** 2) ** (1/2), x)

[image]

whereas for my Calculus I students we have to assume that |a| > |x| otherwise they won't be even able to interpret the results.

The following solution works for question 1:

```
m, n = symbols("m n", real=True, nonzero=True)
integrate(sin(m * x)* cos(n * x), x).args[2][0]
```

[image]

but for question 2 it obviously gives me results more than my Calculus I students can understand:

[image]

whereas I only want:

[image]

instread. Since I already know in question 1 that m!= n and m!=-n, and in question 2 |a| > |x|, is there a way that I can tell sympy this so that I don't have to dig through the Piecewise stuff (or to interpret the complex range result solutions) and get the answer directly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to say that `m` and `n` are not equal (and get the answer you gave) make one odd and one even:

```
>>> var('m',odd=True)
m
>>> var('n',even=True)
n
>>> integrate(sin((m) * x)* cos(n * x), x)
-m*cos(m*x)*cos(n*x)/(m**2 - n**2) - n*sin(m*x)*sin(n*x)/(m**2 - n**2)
```

(You get an interesting result if you just make `m,n,p` positive and let `m=n+p`, do the integral, and replace `p` with `m - n` and simplify. Haven't been able to investigate, though.)

If you want `x` > `a`, let's integrate from `a` to `x` with real variables:

```
>>> var('a x',positive=1)
(a, x)
>>> integrate((a ** 2 - x ** 2) ** (S.Half), (x,a,x))
a**2*asin(x/a)/2 - pi*a**2/4 + x*sqrt(a**2 - x**2)/2
```

If you want to get rid of the constant you can do

```
>>> _.as_independent(x)[1] + Symbol("C")
C + a**2*asin(x/a)/2 + x*sqrt(a**2 - x**2)/2
```

This will only change sign if `x < a < 0`, I b

Comment: Thanks very much, solved my second problem.

Comment: Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what version of SymPy are you using? You can verify that with:

```py
import sympy as sp
print(sp.__version__)
```

If you are using older versions, maybe the solver is having trouble. The following solution has been tested on SymPy 1.9 and 1.10.1.

```py
# define a, x as ordinary symbols with no assumptions. Sadly, it is not
# possible to make assumptions similar to |a| > |x|.
a, x = symbols("a, x")

# integrate the expression
res = integrate(sqrt(a**2 - x**2), x)
print(type(res))
# Piecewise
```

[image]

The result is a `Piecewise` object. As you can see, SymPy computed the complete solution. You can then extract the interested piece with the following command:

```py
res.args[1][0]
```

Here, `res.args[1]` extracts the second piece, which is a tuple, `(expr, condition)`. With `res.args[1][0]` we extract the expression from the second piece.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your post reminding me to post the sympy version. The problem here really is I'm wondering if there's a way to clarify m != n so I can get around using piecewise really. Thanks all the same.